# Taking column value for the if condition in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I'm creating target revision tool to change the old target to new target based on sales percentage. It's difficult to keep all the sale percentage in If formula as conditions. So I added the between value condition (Ex:-1.99%, -1.00%) in Column G and H.

Now the problem is If column C value (Ex: -1.00%) is in between any of the % range in Column G and H, then the target value in Column B (Ex:10) should be Increased/Decreased based on the value in Column I straight to the range in Column G and H (Ex:-1.90%, -1.00% = 10) and calculated as 20 in Column D (revised target).

I'm attaching the screen shot of the excel.

[image: Calculation column]

[image: Condition range]

So far the formula I used is this,

`=IF(AND(G5>=S5:S18,G5<=T5:T18),B5+($U$5:$U$18,U5),B5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the values to add/subtract are following a pattern and to arrive at the value you just need to multiply the rounded percentage by `-5`.

But if that is not suitable, or if you want to change the amounts not to follow a pattern, you can use the table in columns G to H as a lookup table.

In cell D2 use the formula

```
=B2+VLOOKUP(C2,$G$2:$I$15,3,TRUE)
```

Make sure to format column D as General

[image]